# Collapsing container for content

Tags: html, css

I am working on the following website: Public-Journalism.com

In the middle i have the content. It contains three columns/divs: one to the left and right for banners and one in the middle for the actual content. All three are wrapped inside a horizontal bar called div class="midbar_container."

For some reason the middle div takes very rare properties which i have not written. For example sometimes  it ignores the float left property and positions most left while there is another div floated there. Sometimes it takes a width which is equal to that of the full site. I have looked up things like clearfix but nothing seems to help. The code is also very short and quite similar to that of the other two divs but those seem to work as they are supposed to. Could somebody help me to figure out what is wrong?

I have the following html code:

```
<div id="midbar_container">

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/leftcolumn.css"/>      
<div id="leftcolumn">
Linkerkolom
</div>  

<div id="content_container">
Welcome to Public-Journalism.com
</div>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/rightcolumn.css"/>
<div id="rightcolumn">
Rechterkolom
</div>  

</div>
```

And the css code:

```
#midbar_container {
    clear: both;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: yellow;
}

#cotent_container {
    float: left;
    width: 500px;
    background-color: green;
}

#leftcolumn {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: red;
}

#rightcolumn {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

I do have to mention that the css code is being included from different css documents so that i can reuse certain codes on different pages. Could this be the cause?

Comment: You can see for example that the right column is being pushed down a little bit by the content_container. They are all ment to start at the same height as they are all floated left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the below code snippet.
In your css you wrongly named the id `#content_container` as `#cotent_container`.
and I have added some css,Just have a look at it.

```css
#midbar_container {
  
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: yellow;
width:100%
}

#content_container{
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: green;
display:inline-block;
}

#leftcolumn {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: red;
display:inline-block;
}

#rightcolumn {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: red;
display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="midbar_container">

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/leftcolumn.css"/>      
<div id="leftcolumn">
Linkerkolom
</div>  

<div id="content_container">
Welcome to Public-Journalism.com
</div>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/rightcolumn.css"/>
<div id="rightcolumn">
Rechterkolom
</div>  

</div>
```